# Mobile google SERPs return a desktop url instead subdomain mobile url

Tags: google, mobile, search-results

We have desktop and mobile site respectively. `www.example.com` for desktop and `m.example.com` for mobile.

In Google.com mobile SERP, with the search phrase `Weather in aaa(city)` returns mobile subdomain URL `m.example.com/weather/aaa`, however, for a different city (bbb), `weather in bbb (city)` returns `www.example.com/weather/bbb` as it is for the desktop URL.

We have set properly 'alternate' and 'canonical' annotations found on google doc but not sure why a city bbb is returning a desktop site. Please share your thoughts if you have any.

Comment: did you get chance to see if the pages (www.examle.com/weather/bbb) were crawled by mobile bot or not in near future ?

Comment: Yes, they are crawled daily basis. I could see today's date. Some pages are displaying mobile URL so I am thinking need sometime for Google's SERP update.